# JS - Replace all occurence of a string by a variable of its same name

Tags: javascript

I'm receiving long text from a DB which contain strings surrounded by double brackets. I want to replace all these brackets by a string of the same name which I also receive from the DB. For instance :

This is the text I receive :

```
Hi dear {{first_name}}, your age is {{age}}
```

This is the values I receive :

```js
const object = {
  first_name: 'Jack',
  age: 30
}
```

I saw on the Mozilla Developer Network that I can use the replace function which can take 3 args but I don't understand the third parameter.

Am I on the right track ?

Thanks, best regards

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace only shows 2 args

Comment: Not sure where you are getting 3 arguments in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yoou could take a function and the value of the first group (as second parameter).

```js
const
    object = { first_name: 'Jack', age: 30 },
    string = 'Hi dear {{first_name}}, your age is {{age}}',
    result = string.replace(/\{\{([^\}]+)\}\}/g, (_, k) => object[k]);

console.log(result);
```